# QTP not returning FALSE if the webelement doesnt exists

Tags: qtp

I am trying to validate whether a webelement property exists on the page or not. But QTP always returns "true" and not displaying FALSE if the object doesnt exists. Below is my code. Somebody please help

---

```
BlnResult = Browser("CDMS :: Master Agreement").Page("CDMS :: Master Agreement").WebElement("File Upload successfully").Exist(0) Then    
Msgbox BlnResult
```

---

QTP always returns "true" even in case if web element doesnt exist on the page. when tried doing object spy, QTP recognizes the page, but not highlighting anything. Does it mean the object exists (like Hidden )? Please help

Comment: Why have you put Exists(0)? 0 specifies the timeout period. You should have a timeout of 10-20 seconds. Also, please post the html code you are dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

Exist method does not check if the element is visible or not. Even if it is hidden using CSS, it will still return TRUE.

So, Try something like this. (Here we check element coordinates. If it is present in the UI, they will have some coordinates. Not 0)

```
 Set FileUpload = Browser("CDMS :: Master Agreement").Page("CDMS :: Master   Agreement").WebElement("File Upload successfully")

If FileUpload.GetROProperty("x") <> "0" AND FileUpload.GetROProperty("y") <> "0" Then 
  Msgbox "Success"
Else 
  Msgbox "Failed"
End If
```